# Are Phrase lists removed from LUIS?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I used Phrase lists in LUIS in the past. However, the entry is not visible in the left menu anymore even though the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-add-features) says it should be there:

> Open your app by clicking its name on My Apps page, and then click Build, then click Phrase lists in your app's left panel

Are Phrase lists removed from LUIS?

Please see this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of missing Phrase lists]

Comment: Also reported at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26033

Answer (score 2):

A recent fix was deployed. Please refresh the page